# Getting TeXstudio to work in linux mint: File `url.sty' not found.

Tags: linux, latex

just switched to Linux Mint (previous die hard Windows user). I am having some problems trying to get TeXstudio installed.

```
Sudo apt-get install texstudio
```

Gave me a proper installation (at least, that's what I think), but when I try to Build I get the following error:

```
File `url.sty' not found. \let
```

Some googling couldn't help me any further, can you guys help me with this one?

Comment: Have you solved your issue ? Got the same ...

Comment: Well, this is quite embarrassing, but I had to install tex live (the latex compiler) apt-get install texlive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For people that end up over here, I made the beginner mistake of not having a compiler for LaTeX on my pc. This solved the problem:

```
apt-get install texlive
```