# Adding TexLive to TexStudio's understanding of path

Tags: linux, latex

Not sure if this is the right forum for this question (although [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504787/getting-texstudio-to-work-in-linux-mint-file-url-sty-not-found) encouraged me), but I can't get TexStudio to find my installation of TexLive.

I'm running Linux Mint 17.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133235/installing-tex-live-2013-on-linux) by adding `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux` to my `.bashrc` and even added it to both `/etc/profile` and `/etc/environment` just for good measure.

When I start a Terminal, typing `pdflatex` works just fine.

But TexStudio continues not to be able to find the `pdflatex` executable complaining `Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "foo".tex`

So my question is: to what does the texlive install directory have to be added so that TexStudio knows where to find it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to add TeXLive to TeXstudio's `$PATH` through the GUI by following these steps:

1. Open "Configure TeXstudio..." from the "Options" dropdown menu.
2. Check "Show Advanced Options".
3. Go to the "Build" section.
4. In the "Build Options", fill in the TeXLive bin directory in the "Commands ($PATH)" field.

TeXstudio should now find the TeXLive binaries without problem.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and tex-live 2020 and this worked for me. It didn't however when I provided `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux`. Trim the `x86_64-linux` out, and you are good to go.

Comment: I am on a MAC and was not too sure what the exact $PATH was. What worked for me was opening the terminal and tying `which latex`. The terminal returned the path of my latex installation. Copied the path and pasted into the "Commands ($PATH)" field..

Comment: I installed using homebrew and had to follow this instruction to add `/opt/homebrew/bin` to "Commands ($PATH)". Then I had to restart TeXstudio!

Answer (score 5):

Oops... Turns out `/etc/environment` requires a restart before it takes effect.

Rebooted my system and things now work fine. Hat tip to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133242/31839) for giving me the heads up.